# Android-ReactiveLocation change update interval

Tags: android, google-play-services, rx-java

Trying to update Google play service location interval based on user activity using ReactiveLocation ( https://github.com/mcharmas/Android-ReactiveLocation ).  GPS is turned on for the first time, but i dont think the interval is changed based on the activity.

MyLocation class

```
 public MyLocation(Context context) {
     this.context = context;
     startLocationSensor();
 }

 public static MyLocation getInstance(Context context) {
     if ( instance == null){
         Log.i(TAG,"creating new Location sensor");
         instance = new MyLocation(context);
     }
     return instance;
 }


public void startLocationSensor(){

    locationProvider = new ReactiveLocationProvider(context);

    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
          .setFastestInterval(1000 * 10) //Do not receive the updated any frequent than 10 sec
          .setInterval(1000 * 20) // Receive location update every 20 sec
          .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)

    lastKnownLocationObservable = locationProvider
            .getLastKnownLocation()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread());

    activityObservable = locationProvider
            .getDetectedActivity(1000 * 20); // Get updated every 20 sec
    / * setter and getter for the location interval * /
      public void setLocationRequestInterval(long locationRequestInterval) {
        this.locationRequest.setInterval(locationRequestInterval);
    }

      public long getLocationRequestInterval() {
          return this.locationRequest.getInterval();
      }

}
```

In my Service

```
public void onCreate() {
    myLocation = MyLocation.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    startObserving();
}
public void startObserving() {

  Observable<JSONObject>  o1 = /* Accelerometer Sensor obeservable  */

  Observable<JSONObject> o2 = myLocation.getActivityObservable()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .map(new ToMostProbableActivity())
        .map(new DetectedActivityToJson())
        .doOnError(new ErrorHandler());

  Observable<JSONObject> o3 = myLocation.getLocationUpdatesObservable()
        .observeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .map(new LocationToJsonFunc())
        .doOnError(new ErrorHandler());


r = Observable.combineLatest(o1, o2, o3, new Func4<JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject, JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public JSONObject call(JSONObject s1, JSONObject s2, JSONObject s3) {
            return someCombinedJsonObject
        }
    }).filter(new Func1<JSONObject, Boolean>() {
              @Override
              public Boolean call(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                  acty = "get current activity from jsonObject"
                  float LocationRequestInterval = myLocation.getLocationRequestInterval();

                  if (acty.equalsIgnoreCase("still")) {
                      sendMessage = false; // Not interested in these message
                      if (LocationRequestInterval == 1000*20){
                          Log.d(TAG,"Dont need frequent updates, set to longer interval");
                          myLocation.setLocationRequestInterval(1000 * 60 * 15); // 15 minutes
                      }

                  } else {
                      if (LocationRequestInterval == 1000*60*15){
                          Log.d(TAG,"user is moving so need  frequent updates");
                          myLocation.setLocationRequestInterval(1000 * 20); // get location update every 20 seconds
                      }

                  }
                  return sendMessage;
              }
          }
);




//subscribe to the combined observable and perform update
combinedDataSubscription = r
        .sample(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .subscribe(new Action1<JSONObject>() {
                       @Override
                       public void call(JSONObject resultJson) {
                              doSomethingwithData(resultJson);
                       }
                   }

        );

}
```

Comment: You have defined intervals at 3 different levels (20 sec, 15 min and 5 sec). Did you checked with the log statements that all the 3 blocks are executing when satisfies the condition? Also check to see if you have the latest version of Google Play Services being referred by your app project.

Comment: @AniV checked and all the block statements are executed ok. I have amemded the interval in above code. Reactive-Location is using 7.5.0 and rxjava 1.0.13.